# Number to Roman in Javascript

Tags: javascript, roman-numerals

Is this a good solution for the Number to Roman Numerals Kata in Javascript?

```
function toRomans(n) {
    var nString = n.toString();
    var result = "";
    var allLetters = [["I", "V", "X"], ["X", "L", "C"], ["C", "D", "M"], ["M"]];
    var letterSet = nString.length - 1;
    for (var index in nString) {
        result = result + conversor(nString[index], allLetters[letterSet]);
        letterSet --;
    }
    console.log(n + " --> " + result);
}

function conversor(digit, letterSet) {
    switch(digit) {
        case "1":
            return letterSet[0];
            break;

        case "2":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
            break;

        case "3":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
            break;

        case "4":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[1];
            break;

        case "5":
            return letterSet[1];
            break;

        case "6":
            return letterSet[1] + letterSet[0];
            break;

        case "7":
            return letterSet[1] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
            break;

        case "8":
            return letterSet[1] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
            break;

        case "9":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[2];
            break;

        case "0":
            // skip character
            return "";
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

}

toRomans(2);
toRomans(7);
toRomans(32);
toRomans(456)
toRomans(1243);
toRomans(3500);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Invalid input

```
toRomans(21463);
```

There we go. I broke your function. Sorry.

Even though the [Roman Numerals Kata](http://agilekatas.co.uk/katas/romannumerals-kata.html) specifies that only numbers between 1 and 3000 needs to be returned correctly, I think it is better to handle numbers outside the working range in a specific way, such as throwing an exception.

#### Return, do not log

Imagine that I am writing a program and I want to use your method to count how many unique characters there is in the resulting string.

```
console.log(n + " --> " + result);
```

This doesn't let me do that, really. It would be much better to do:

```
return result;
```

And then I can log, show an alert, or count the number of unique characters *after* calling the function. This is how it is properly done in programming.

`console.log(toRomans(56));` is more clear what the code is doing than simply `toRomans(56);`

#### Returning and breaking

In your `switch` statement, you don't need both `return` and `break`. When calling `return`, the method ends, so further statements will not be executed. Your breaks are dead code that will never be called.

I would also `return "";` in the *default* case as well, which lets `0` be handled together with `default`.

```
function conversor(digit, letterSet) {
    switch(digit) {
        case "1":
            return letterSet[0];
        case "2":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
        case "3":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
        case "4":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[1];
        case "5":
            return letterSet[1];
        case "6":
            return letterSet[1] + letterSet[0];
        case "7":
            return letterSet[1] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
        case "8":
            return letterSet[1] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0] + letterSet[0];
        case "9":
            return letterSet[0] + letterSet[2];
        default:
            return "";
        }
}
```

I believe the `conversor` function can be further optimized, but I'll leave as-is for now.

Comment: yes, I removed the code to handle incorrect inputs due to the kata instructions. The rest is very helpful

Comment: @PedroGonzalez The kata instructions doesn't specify how you should handle incorrect inputs, so you are free to throw an exception for those.